# Check react-routes in run-time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there a way in react-router to check in the browser (e.g. using dev tools) what is the active set of routes that was eventually registered in the app in run-time?

Comment: Does `withRouter(<App />)` then `console.log(this.props)` show the stuff you want to check?

Comment: @FisNaN depending on the app structure, the App component may or may not the right place to check. However, seems like I had got wrong about how the router works in the first place.
From what I've eventually understood I can say that the routes written in the render function of a specific component will only be checked when this component is being rendered. Meaning ... there is no such thing as "Global initial registration" or the routes used.

Comment: I'm not sure about "Global initial registration", but `history` is a property (not state) in `BrowserRouter`. So when `BrowserRouter` is used as high order component on top of `<App/>`, `history` can be made available for all children. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js Does this same as your understanding?

Comment: @FisNaN actually the BrowserRouter and `history` property are new to me and the flow you mentioned is really benefitial to my work. However, my confusion was about "when" routing was carried on and by "who". I come from a PHP Laravel background where the router runs only once before the controllers handle the requests. That made me confused about react-route which can match the requested URL any number of time inside `render` functions.

Comment: It's hard to answer your due to the lack of specific example, but I'm grad I could help. BTW when you think React, all elements are pure JS function which created by `React.createElement()`, the JSX is just a syntax sugar to make writing component easier.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I arrive to the conclusion that react-router doesn't have a **global registry of routes** to start with. Rather, the routes are matched in the `render` functions every time the cycle arrive at them.

Unfortunately, react-router doesn't yet support knowing all the matches that happened since the root component until the child one.